# How to create an STL output iterator for a Eigen matrix?

Tags: c++, stl, iterator, eigen

Say you have an `Eigen::Matrix<float, Eigen::Dynamic, 3> m;`. Now you have data outside Eigen and want to move it into your matrix using an STL algorithm (e.g. `std::transform`). The [documentation](https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox-devel/group__TutorialSTL.html) gives examples on how to use `m.rowwise()` in a range-based for loop. However, passing `m.rowwise()` as the output iterator of `std::transform` does not work. It complains that `VectorwiseOp` does not have an `operator++`. A range-based for loop would call the `begin()` method of the range expression anyhow, but the `VectorwiseOp` [does not have](https://sources.debian.org/src/eigen3/3.3.7-1/Eigen/src/Core/VectorwiseOp.h/) a `begin()` method.

Say I have a `std::vector<std::tuple<float, float, float>> i;`. How would I transform that into the matrix? Of course one can use a plain loop over an index variable here, but that becomes difficult when using more complex input data structures. Then, one can use `std::for_each` and maintain the output index externally, but that seems clumsy. I'm looking for something like

```
std::transform(
    i.cbegin(),
    i.cend(),
    /* TODO: something like m.rowwise() */,
    [](const std::tuple<float, float, float> &e) -> /* TODO */ {
        /* don't care here */
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Eigen::VectorwiseOp<ET, D>` gains an appropriate `begin` and `end` in Eigen 3.4, you were looking at the source for 3.3.

If you upgrade to 3.4, it's simply

```
std::transform(
    i.cbegin(),
    i.cend(),
    m.rowwise().begin(),
    [](const std::tuple<float, float, float> &e) -> decltype(*m.rowwise().begin()) {
        /* don't care here */
    });
```

Comment: I note that the homepage presently says "The latest stable release is Eigen 3.3.7."